# VBA Using Input Box to collect Various Strings From User to search For

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to create a vba code that asks the user for a number, n,  of keywords he/she is looking for, then to create n number of input boxes to get each keyword and store it as a string. I'm unsure of the best way to do this, I don't know if a loop should be used here, and if it should be used, how to code it. Here's what I have so far...

```
Sub GetKeywords()
Dim numKey As Integer
numKey = InputBox("How many keywords would you like to search for? (Integer)")

For i = 1 To numKey
    keywordi = InputBox("Please enter keyword")


Next

End Sub
```

In the for loop I want to create n variables (keyword1, keyword 2, ..., keywordn) that are stored and passed into a different sub for searching of those keywords in a webpage. What I am having trouble with is how to declare an n amount of string variables and assigning those a value based on user input. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Protip: whenever you feel the need to append a number to the end of a variable's name, a big red flashing light/flag should pop up. If you have *n* related values that you can index/number, then you need an array, a collection, or *some kind* of data structure. Also, `InputBox` was meant as a developer tool, not for user interface. Consider using a worksheet to hold user data, or make a `UserForm` to make a proper UI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot create variables on the fly like you have written. I suggest getting the number first and then storing the keywords into a sheet. Or better yet, just creating a worksheet that allows the user to enter `n` number of keywords into a range that you then process. In this way, you don't need `Input Boxes` and its less cumbersome.

If you want `InputBoxes`, use this:

```
Sub GetKeywords()

Dim numKey As Integer
numKey = InputBox("How many keywords would you like to search for? (Integer)")

For i = 1 To numKey

    Dim keyword as String
    keyword = InputBox("Please enter keyword " & i)

    Dim ws as Worksheet
    Set ws = Worksheets("reference") 'change name as needed

    ws.Range("A" & i).Value = keyword    

Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks! that makes much more sense and seems simpler. However, I am getting a Run-Time error 9: Subscript out of range for " Set ws = Worksheets("reference")"

Comment: Read Scott Holtzman comment in his code... change name as needed.  This must be YOUR worksheet's name.

Comment: got it, made it the active sheet. 

the next issue that arises, is after these keywords are put into the excel cells, the next sub declares the string strTemp as the keyword to search for, How do I set all the keywords in the excel cells as the strTemp to be searched for?

Comment: @A.Cod - that's a new question. Please post as a seperate question.